# how can I refresh in angular using jboss 6.4?

Tags: angular, jboss, angular6, jboss6.x

i've already configured the standalone.xml file in this way inside subsystem tags:

```
<rewrite name="rule-2" pattern="^((?!.*(rest)).*)\/([\w\-]+)\/([\w\-]+)$" substitution="/$1/index.html" flags="L"/>      
        <rewrite name="rule-3" pattern="^((?!.*(rest)).*)\/([\w\-]+)$" substitution="/$1/index.html" flags="L"/>
```

I should redirect all the url to index letting those that contain the word "rest" pass, I think that these regexes must work but I get a blank page to refresh without errors.
I have already set the base-href like this: / myApp /

using these two regex alternatives:

```
rewrite name="rule-1" pattern="^/(.*)/([\w\-]+)/([\w\-]+)$" substitution="/$1/index.html" flags="L"/>      
        <rewrite name="rule-2" pattern="^/(.*)/([\w\-]+)$" substitution="/$1/index.html" flags="L"/>
```

everything works but all the URLs containing the word "rest" are also redirected, so backend calls do not work

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
 To validate your regex patterns use a tool, eg. https://regex101.com

Second:
On the first rule, the  is excluded as in: !.*(rest))
Therefore, in regards to  you will also need to add a exclusion as well, or a condition.

Cli command applying rule for Jboss web:

```
#/subsystem=web/virtual-server=default-host/rewrite=jboss:add(pattern="^/$", substitution="/example/", flags="L,R=302")
```

Third:
Regarding refreshing, for any property in JBoss you must reload the server using the CLI command

:reload

Hope that helps